Why is this subprocess command not timing-out properly?
So I have this simple POC
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.run('cmd', timeout=1, shell=True, capture_output=True)

it is not raising a TimeoutError after the given interval (which is 1 second in this case)
and it seems like the timeout flag in the subprocess.run() is working just fine in Linux but seems to produce bugs in windows
For example
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.run('ping -n 10 127.0.0.1', shell=True, capture_output=True, timeout=1)

Seems to not raise the timeout error untill after the command completes
Edit of what I tried and the output:
C:\Users\zaid2\Documents>type t.py
import subprocess
import time

s = time.time()
try:
    roc = subprocess.run('ping -n 10 127.0.0.1', shell=True, capture_output=True, timeout=1)
finally:
    print(f'\nFinished in {round(time.time() - s)} seconds.\n\n')
C:\Users\zaid2\Documents>python t.py

Finished in 9 seconds.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zaid2\Documents\t.py", line 6, in <module>
    roc = subprocess.run('ping -n 10 127.0.0.1', shell=True, capture_output=True, timeout=1)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zaid2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 550, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zaid2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1209, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zaid2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1628, in _communicate
    raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, orig_timeout)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command 'ping -n 10 127.0.0.1' timed out after 1 seconds

C:\Users\zaid2\Documents>python --version
Python 3.11.8


Does it work if you don't use shell=True?

Yes it does work

Sounds like the shell is blocking/ignoring the kill signal that gets sent when the timeout occurs.

@Barmar since some commands do not work unless shell=True is specified (like dir) how can I solve this? I need to use shell=True but also have timeouts

No idea. I don't see this mentioned as a known limitation on Windows in the documentation. Are you using a nonstandard shell?

No I am using the normal command prompt, also tried powershell still same thing

see my 'answer' ... works for me, show ALL input/output as i have not just selected bits.

Possible relevant Python bug (not fixed): https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87512

You could try with capture_output = False and see if that still hangs; if not, then it’s probably that linked bug. Unfortunately, this isn’t going to be an easy fix; one workaround might be to have the command redirect to a temp file, then read the temp file.

The CPython fix should definitely be to apply a timeout on the communicate read. I don’t know why they don’t have that already; seems like it wouldn’t be a hard fix (just use async I/O?)

Already did use asyncio however this time it is giving an error (which does not really effect the programs flow only outputs the error when the script extis) the error is
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

made my own timeout implementation using Popen
import subprocess
import time


def run_command_with_timeout(cmd, timeout):
    start_time = time.time()
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


    while time.time() - start_time < timeout:
        if process.poll() is not None:
            return process.communicate()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    else:
        process.kill()
        raise TimeoutError




if __name__ == "__main__":
    stdout, stderr = run_command_with_timeout('ping -n 10 google.com', timeout=1)
    if stdout:
        print(stdout.decode())
    if stderr:
        print(stderr.decode())
    print("Process finished")


Have you tried looking at the source code to see what you're doing differently that allows it to work?

Yes to basically in the initial source code of subprocess.run() it actually passes the timeout to process.communicate() which is causing the program to freeze and not raise the error until the process is finished, however in my implementation I am running the process in a different thread and checking for the timeout in the main thread.
